# Is there a C++ execution/data model like that of Python?

Tags: c++, scope, parameter-passing

Python has documents [execution model](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/executionmodel.html) and [data model](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html), explaining all about names, bindings, namespaces, and objects.

For instance, it tells us that :

- names can be bound and rebound to objects
- there are mutable and immutable objects
- doing `a = 5; b = a` results in `b` and `a` now point to the same object
- functions are call-by-object

Can someone answer similarly analogously for C++, for us to understand,

- can names be bound and rebound to objects? Is that what a reference is?
- are there immutable and mutable objects? are they similar to python?
- doing `a = 5; b = a` results in `b` and `a` referring to two different memory-locations with the same value(?)
- are functions uniformly call-by-value? if a reference to a variable is just another name, then how come suddenly the function doesn't copy the value the same way it does when the "primary" name of the variable is used?

I wish to emphasise the comparative aspect here: what mappings are exactly the same, and which ones are different, and in what way? Is there a similar (official, perhaps?) document explaining clearly how these aspects work in C++?

Answer (score 2):

You won't find very comparable documents because Python and C++ are very different. I typically send people to [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language) when people ask questions about what C++ provides.

For C++'s "execution model", you'll want to look at [names and identifiers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/identifiers), [name lookup](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lookup), [order of evaluation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order), [linkage](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/language_linkage), and others.

For C++'s "data model", you'll want to look at [initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initialization), [classes](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class), [constructors](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list), and many others. It seems the Python page is largely concerned with standard class functions which C++ really doesn't have beyond constructors, destructors, and assignment operators.

If you want anything more specific, then you'd have to look at the standard specification. [c++14 working draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4296.pdf)

Comment: the linked working draft says on its first page "...It's known to be incomplet and incorrekt,...". Maybe not the best resource to learn the language properly

Comment: note that the actual C++14 official standard is a $200 investment, though the working drafts are free and 99.9999% the content.

Comment: actually I wasnt aware of this, nevertheless, wouldnt a working draft of C++11 be a more reliable resource?

Comment: that would depend on which version you're targeting I suppose. I just linked it for C++14 because it was more modern.

Answer (score 0):

C++ is a ISO standard and described in the *ISO/IEC 14882:2014* formal and legal document.